# How to pass value from checkbox to field formset in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I make a button inside a table Product. When I click on the button will display popup table for user choose items by checkbox. I'm using formset to make row in table. But my button to insert items to table Product is not working. 
Popup table for choose items:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
                     aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Search Product</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="col-lg-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="search"
                                                                      name="txtSearch"
                                                                      placeholder="Search"></div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn start" id="btnSearch" name="btnSearch">
                                                <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                <span></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div class="adv-table">
                                                <table id="tblData"
                                                       class="display table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
                                                    <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Name</th>
                                                        <th>Supplier</th>
                                                        <th>Sale Code</th>
                                                        <th>Purchase Code</th>
                                                        <th></th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    {% if supplier_item %}
                                                        <tbody>
                                                        {% for i in supplier_item %}
                                                            <tr class="gradeX">
                                                                <td>{{ i.item.name }}</td>
                                                                <td>{{ i.supplier.name }}</td>
                                                                <td>{{ i.price }}</td>
                                                                <td>{{ i.quantity }}</td>
                                                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="choices"
                                                                           id="{{ i.item.id }}"
                                                                           value="{{ i.item.name }}">
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        {% endfor %}
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    {% endif %}
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="btnAddItems">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
            else
                $(this).removeAttr('checked');
        });
        $('#btnAddItems').on('click', function () {
                debugger;
                var allVals = [];
                $('input[checked=checked]').each(function () {
                    allVals.push($(this).val());
                })
                return allVals;
                cloneMore('#dynamic-table tr.gradeX:last', 'form', allVals);

                function cloneMore(selector, type, allVals) {
                    for (i = 0; i < allVals.length; i++) {
                        var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
                        var total = $('#id_' + type + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
                        newElement.find(':input').each(function () {
                            var name = $(this).attr('name').replace('-' +       (total - 1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
                            var id = 'id_' + name;
                            var value = allVals[i];
                            $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id, 'value': value}).val('').removeAttr('checked');
                        });
                        newElement.find('label').each(function () {
                            var newFor = $(this).attr('for').replace('-' + (total - 1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
                            $(this).attr('for', newFor);
                        });
                        total++;
                        $('#id_' + type + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
                        $(selector).after(newElement);
                    }
                };
            });
    });
```

Comment: Why have you written `btnAddItems` `click event` inside `checkbox` `click event`? and what selector is `$('input[checked=checked]')` good for?

Comment: If I put btnAddItems click event outside checkbox click event then my btnAddItems cannot click and selector $('input[checked=checked]') to get all item have already checked by user

Comment: To get all the item checked by user you need to use `$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')`. For your first question, I might need more detail to answer...

Comment: I so sorry about my mistake. I have already put btnAddItems click event outside checkbox click event and can you help me check the function cloneMore?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors in browser?

Comment: It not display error in browser but it sert a new row in table Product without display value from checkbox although I check it have value="xxx". And display a warning message in console: The specified value "xxx" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

Comment: Then its having some invalid value which you had put a rule with `regex`